# best UI framework or langages for developing a winform application

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, user-interface, vcl

Can someone suggest a good UI framework for WinForms development? i need a good and free framework to develop a simple winform application

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WinForms (ie: Windows Forms) **is** a UI Framework.  Just use it.

If you want WinForms, this will limit you to .NET language options.  The most common of these is C#, which also has the most examples.

That being said, if you just want Windows user interface development, WPF has many advantages over Windows Forms.  It is likely also best done via C#, though.

Comment: Qt Or MFC or VCL or winforms .net or WPF or Use ComponentOne (C1 is not free!) Or ..
any other Suggestion?

Comment: i would to develop a simple application. Just i need the complet solution for design and database access

Comment: @BestHumain WPF is my favorite option.